# Jdeveloper PL/SQL Web Service - Procedures with SYS_REFCURSOR parameter

Tags: web-services, soap, plsql, jdeveloper

I am trying to expose a PL/SQL Package as a SOAP Web Service. I am using "Publish as JAX-RPC Web Service option in Jdeveloper 11g. This brings up the web services wizard that lets you define your data source , SOAP binding , package units one wants to expose , type mappings , security policies and so on ....

I am trying to include the following procedure in the web service. It takes in a SYS_REFCURSOR type as an input.

```
  PROCEDURE print_max_sal_all_dept(myCursor SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
   dept_id employees.department_id%type;
   emp_lname employees.last_name%type;
   m_salary employees.salary%type;
  BEGIN
    LOOP
     FETCH myCursor INTO  dept_id , emp_lname , m_salary;
     dbms_output.put_line('At department with Id: '|| dept_id || 'employee with last name: ' || emp_lname || 'earns the maximum salary of : ' || m_salary);
     EXIT WHEN myCursor%notfound;
    END LOOP;
  END print_max_sal_all_dept;
```

The Jdeveloper Wizard for some reason does has this procedure grayed out in the "Program Units" section in the "PL/SQL Web Services Editor".

Is there a reason why the wizard would not allow exposing a procedure that takes in a "SYS_REFCURSOR"
type input?  This is not documented anywhere in Chapter 16 of the Jdeveloper manual.

The only listed limitation of the wizard is not being able to expose program units that return REF CURSOR type.

Am I missing something here ?